# inline bash time variable expansion

Tags: bash

In a bash script I"m ssh-ing into another box; running 1 script and then another; I"m trying to get a rough time about how long that first script is taking to run.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Test Time Stamp"
STARTTIME=`date +%s`
ssh username@000.000.000.000 'scriptToRun.bat echo$?;/path/to/script.py '$STARTTIME `date +%s`'; exit $$?
```

STARTTIME and the second `date +%s` get the same value.

if i do something like the following

```
`date +%s`; sleep 10; `date +%s`
```

This seems to work.

Comment: Just execute it with `time` in the beginning: `time /path/to/script.sh`

Comment: or use date after ssh line, or write a wrapper for the remote side and use a single ssh statement `ssh user@remote timeAndExec.bat`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, the `date` in this command:

```
ssh user@remote.com script `date`
```

is executed before ssh, similar to this case:

```
ssh user@remote.com process.bat $(ls .*a)
```

You can escape backticks and make the remote side execute that part, however, using `time`:

```
time ssh ....
```

or, doing it after ssh line:

```
date
ssh
date
```

would be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You get the same time because following line

ssh username@000.000.000.000 'scriptToRun.bat echo$?;/path/to/script.py '$STARTTIME `date +%s`'

is evaluated before execution.